# How do I display the data from a database table via EJB in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, ejb

I need to display a database table in JSP.

I have a session bean that contains a method to display all the data found in the database.

How do I use it in JSP?

Code (from comment below):

```
@Override public List findAll() { 
   String flightQuery = "SELECT f FROM Flights f"; 
   Query q = em.createQuery(flightQuery); 
   List existing = q.getResultList(); 

   if (existing.isEmpty()) { 
       System.out.println("Invalid");
   }
   return existing; 
}
```

JSP Code

```
<c:forEach items="${flights}" var="flight"> 
   <tr> 
   <td>${flight.flightid}</td> 
   <td><c:out value="${flight.flightnumber}" /></td> 
   <td><c:out value="${flight.datetime}" /></td> 
   <td><c:out value = "${flight.seatsleft}"</td> 
   <td><c:out value="${flight.id}" /></td> 
   <td><c:out value="${flight.price}" /></td> 
   <td><c:out value="${flight.originairport}" /></td> 
   <td><c:out value="${flight.destinationairport}" /></td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach> 
</table>
```

It is not displaying in a table.

Comment: Post any and all code you have written at this time; include your table structure (name and columns) and this "session mean" you refer to.

Comment: `<jsp:include page="servlet"/>` and call a servlet where you use that bean.

Comment: @AdriánLópez: that's a bad practice. JSP is the view, not the controller.

Comment: @BalusC I know, but as his question says that the method 'displays' I understood he had a method with prints or something, so its the only idea I was able to come up with :)

Comment: yes i have a method :  @Override 
       public List findAll()
       {
       String flightQuery = "SELECT f FROM Flights f";
       Query q   = em.createQuery(flightQuery);
      
       
       List existing = q.getResultList();
       
       if (existing.isEmpty()) {
           System.out.println("Invalid");
       }
      
      return existing;
       }

Answer (score 3):

Use a controller servlet. A basic example which performs exaclty the desired job is already demonstrated in [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), under the section "Hello World #2 (preprocess a request)", about halfway the page. You can inject the EJB just straight in the servlet using `@EJB` annotation.

Here's an extract of relevance:

```
@WebServlet("/products")
public class ProductServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private ProductService productService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Product> products = productService.list();
        request.setAttribute("products", products);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

And then in JSP:

```html
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
    <tr>
        <td>${product.id}</td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.name}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.description}" /></td>
        <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price}" type="currency" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Finally just invoke the servlet by its URL: `http://localhost:8080/context/products`.

Comment: Yeah, thats the right way. Doesn't use the method in his Session Bean though.

Comment: @AdriánLópez: look closer, it's the `list()` method.

Comment: Oh sorry. Nice answer then, upvoted.

Comment: thanks for your help I tried this :

Comment: <c:forEach items="${flights}" var="flight">
    <tr>
        <td>${flight.flightid}</td>
        <td><c:out value="${flight.flightnumber}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${flight.datetime}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value = "${flight.seatsleft}"</td>
        <td><c:out value="${flight.id}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${flight.price}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${flight.originairport}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${flight.destinationairport}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
    </table>
it is nit displaying data in table

Comment: Rightclick page in browser, *View Source*. Do you see JSTL tags or not? If so, then they did not run. Perhaps you forgot to install JSTL or to declare JSTL core taglib? For the answer, start at our servlets wiki page.

Comment: Your posted code c:forEach does not include an open `<table>`

Comment: @JoshDM: the remainder can be found in the servlets wiki page. Just omitting not-so-relevant parts.

Comment: @BalusC - I was referring to the text posted by mary borg from 3 comments up, which has since been incorporated, formatted, into her initial question with her subsequent follow-up question.